# Better way to read list of object and generate JSON object

Tags: java, json

I have a following list of objects

```
[ ObjectVO ( id = 151401 , code = 370 AAA , Origin id = 8628823 , state = SP , local = N , number = 998035 ) N , number=998039), ObjectVO(id=151401, code=370 AAA, Origin ID=8628853, state=SP, local=N , number=998041), ObjectVO(id=151402, code=371 AAA, Origin ID=8 state=SP, local=N, number=998035), ObjectVO(id=151402, code=371 MCC, Origin id=8628833, state=SP, local=N, number=998039), ObjectVO(id=151402, code=371). AAA, Origin ID=8628853, state=SP, local=N, number=998041),
ObjectVO ( id = 155852 , code = 0389 AAA , Origin id = 8627130 , state = SP , local = N , number = 996509 ) , number=996509)]
```

through desse list manage to json structure below:

```
[
    {
       "id":151401,
       "observation":"370 AAA",
       "input":[
          {
             "id":0,
             "state":"string"
             "local":"string"
             "number":0
          },
          {
             "id":8628833,
             "state":"SP"
             "local":"N",
             "number":9
          } }
       ]
    } }
]
```

Create the following code for this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Map<String,Object>> originalMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
for(Entry<Object, List<VoqueryBatch>> entry :
    map1.entrySet()) {
    originalMap . add ( entry . getKey ( ) . toString ( ) , Map . of (
    "id", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getId,
    "code", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getCode(),
    "idOrigin", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getIdOrigin(),
    "state", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getState(),
    "local", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getLocal(),
    "number", entry.getValue().iterator().next().getNumber()
));
} }

List<ObjectNode> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for ( String entry : originalMap . keySet ()) {
List<Map<String, Object>> list = originalMap.get(entry);
ObjectNode objNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
objNode.put("id", (Long)lotList.get(0).get("id"));
objNode.put("observation", (String) list.get(0).get("observation"));
ArrayNode array = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();
for ( Map < String , Object > myObj : list ) {
ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
node.put("id", (Long) myObj.get("idOrigin"));
node.put("up", (String) myObj.get("state));
node.put("series", (String) myObj.get("local"));
node.put("number", (Long) myObj.get("number"));
array . add ( node ) ;
} }
lotNode.set("input", array);
newList . add ( node ) ;
} }

String jsonOutput = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(newList);
```

Using a Map for that case makes more sense than using List, anyone have a better way to implement?

Thank you.

Comment: post the actual classes, it's hard understand the structure from output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jackson` as you wish https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson .

Anyway, issue [Deserialize JSON array to Map using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007668/deserialize-json-array-to-map-using-jackson) might be helpful.

By the way, methods `ObjectMapper#readValue` should be enough for most use cases.

For example:

```java
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference<T> valueTypeRef);
```

You can deserialize `json` string into whatever class as you wish:

```java
//...
public static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
//... to deserialize to List<Map<String,Object>>
MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Map<String,Object>>>(){});
```

Let me know if any thing need to be updated.